# Why isn't OS X Spotlight or Finder finding a file by content that I know exists?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

I've got several files in a few folders that I know contain a word, say "foo".  I've manually found some of those files, but neither Spotlight or Finder's search is showing those files as matches nor any of the others that certainly exist.  I assume that the files need to be indexed by the OS.  Is this true?  If it is, how do I "fix" it?

Answer (score 2):

It might be that indexing is broken on your drive for some reason (perhaps a corrupt file, etc.)

You might want to follow the steps outlined in [this Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2409) to reindex the files on your volume.

What sort of files contain this word? Perhaps the files are in some kind of binary format that isn't indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight doesn't index every file in your system. Depending on where it is or what kind it is, you may have to recur to *Terminal* or 3rd parties such as [Find Any File](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.html) or [EasyFind](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/freeware/), which can search for content

[image: cool]